# UIButton Images appear in launch screen before their fade in animation begins

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

So I have a video playing in the background and two button images that fade in. Both work fine, however on the simulator when I launch the app, I see the button images on the white screen then it goes into playing the video and the animation. I also have the alpha set to 0 in the main story board on each image. Not sure if this is a simulator/launch screen glitch or my code. My code is below and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import MediaPlayer


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loginAlpha: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var signupAlpha: UIButton!


    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var paused: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // code for background video

                let theURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("test", withExtension: "mp4")

                avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: theURL!)
                avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
                avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                avPlayer.volume = 0
                avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None

                avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
                view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, atIndex: 0)

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                    selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",
                    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
                    object: avPlayer.currentItem)
            }

            func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
                let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
                p.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
            }

            override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
                signupAlpha.alpha = 0
                loginAlpha.alpha = 0

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.signupAlpha.alpha = 1.0
                    self.loginAlpha.alpha = 1.0

                    }, completion: nil)

                    avPlayer.play()
                    paused = false
            }

            override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
                avPlayer.pause()
                paused = true
            }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: Try adding this lines `signupAlpha.alpha = 0` and `loginAlpha.alpha = 0` on viewDidLoad

Comment: I had tried that initially, moving it and even copying it and it had the same result. What's interesting is that I moved the buttons around in the main storyboard, and the image i see on the launch screen shows the buttons where they were initially placed, however when the app goes through the rest of the code and runs the video and animation the buttons are where they are placed in the main storyboard now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for this:

on `viewDidLoad` ( You can set this on storyboard too. )

```
    loginAlpha.hidden = true
    signupAlpha.hidden = true
```

and on `viewDidAppear`

```
    signupAlpha.alpha = 0
    loginAlpha.alpha = 0
    loginAlpha.hidden = false
    signupAlpha.hidden = false
```